# Значение выражения "вверх по улице"

Tags: семантика

Здравствуйте! Что означает выражение "вверх по улице" (вниз по улице) по отношению к изменению нумерации домов? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Ну в моем городе нумерация домов на улицах, которые расположены на склонах, совпадает с рельефом, поэтому выражение "вверх по Тихоокеанской" или "вниз по Компроспекту" означает именно то, что означает, и слух не корежит. Однако ни разу не доводилось слышать, чтобы говорилось "вниз по Комсомольской" или "вверх по Ленина" (они по равнине идут).

Answer (score 1):

В портовых городах улицы нумеровались строго от моря. Так что "вверх" соответствовало строго увеличению номеров. С тех пор это представление ушло (везде, кроме англоязычных стран). В России, где улицы могут подниматься и опускаться, пересекать речки и овраги, привязки к нумерации давно нет (как и самой нумерации домов не было до второй половины XIX века как минимум), хотя где-то она, естественно, могла сохраниться. Так что лучше ориентироваться на контекст. "Вверх по улице" скорее всего означает "в гору".

Answer (score 0):

Гм... Ну, это может быть и буквально (например, я живу на склоне горы, где улицы, действительно, идут сверху вниз, и нумерация домов увеличивается снизу вверх). Но, если речь о ровной местности, то, скорее всего, имеется в виду: увеличение номеров - вверх, уменьшение - вниз. По логике - так.